# checking for existence of a value in a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a small dataframe, df,  that I am testing some code on, before using the code on a larger set

```
  id  make   price
  21  Boss    300
  22    LG    400
  23    EE    500
  24  Orange  750
```

I am trying to find a way of determining if a value already exists in a column before inserting that value.

This code snippet works

```
newval = 'EE'
for val in df.make:
    if val == newval:
        print(val)
    else:
        print('not the val')
```

However this snippet, that should more cleanly identify if a value already exists in a specific column of the dataframe, does not appear to work in that it prints 'Available to add', despite 'EE' already existing in the 'make' column.

```
newval = 'EE'
if newval in df.make:
    print('In there already')
else:
    print('Available to add')
```

If I test for true or false

```
exists = 'EE' in df.make
print(exists)
```

I get False, despite the fact that 'EE' is clearly already in the 'make' column

Why am I not getting True and 'Available to add'

I am sure that I am missing something very simple but cannot see it. Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: do you already have all the new values in a list? it would be easier to find the set difference than to loop each `newval`

Comment: I am actually trying to test some logic to use in a Post function within an API where I might send in a new record periodically and don't want the process to allow duplicate records .. I think I can see the sense in what you suggest but maybe my use case is a bit specific

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Has some of BEN-YO's suggested solution within it

Comment: I know, it's good that you found a solution, but we should avoid keeping duplicate questions, pleace accept the notice shown on top of the question so it is marked as dup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in to `isin` follow by `any`

```
exists =  df.make.isin(['EE']).any()
```

Comment: Thank you. Exists now gives me a True. I'll play with this inside my if, else statement to get behaving too

Answer (score 0):

Your statement `'EE' in df.make` is searching for the string in the series INDEX, that's why it returns False. If you change it to `'EE' in df.make.values` then it will be True.